# Spring cloud stream mutually exclusive property issue

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have application.yml configuration i.e

```
cloud:
    stream:
      poller:
        # Cron for polling data.
        cron: 0 0/30 * * * *
        ........
```

I am facing errors like

```
Description:

The following configuration properties are mutually exclusive:

    spring.integration.poller.cron
    spring.integration.poller.fixed-delay
    spring.integration.poller.fixed-rate

However, more than one of those properties has been configured at the same time:

    spring.integration.poller.cron
    spring.integration.poller.fixed-delay


Action:

Update your configuration so that only one of the mutually exclusive properties is configured.
```

Even though I haven't added fix-delay it shows that I have added it.

I saw that PollerConfigEnvironmentPostProcessor class adds `fixed-delay` if the property is absent. So how can I use the cron expression?

```
//TODO Must remain after removal of deprecated code above in the future
        streamPollerProperties.putIfAbsent(INTEGRATION_PROPERTY_PREFIX + "fixed-delay", "1s");
        streamPollerProperties.putIfAbsent(INTEGRATION_PROPERTY_PREFIX + "max-messages-per-poll", "1");
```

I have also checked with spring integration poller properties instead of spring cloud stream poller as it is deprecated but getting the same error

```
 integration:
    poller:
      cron: 0 0/30 * * * *
```

Earlier with spring cloud version **2020.0.2**, it was working fine. As soon as I update the spring cloud version to **2021.0.1**, error gets started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug. That:

```
streamPollerProperties.putIfAbsent(INTEGRATION_PROPERTY_PREFIX + "fixed-delay", "1s");
```

has to be conditional if there is no `spring.integration.poller.fixed-delay` or `spring.integration.poller.cron` present yet.

As a workaround I suggest to implement an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` like this:

```
public class RemoveStreamPollerEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override 
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        environment.getPropertySources().remove("spring.integration.poller");
    }

}
```

This way all the `spring.integration.poller.` properties related to Spring Cloud Stream will be removed from the environment. But those configured manually based on the `spring.integration.poller.` will still be present.

Therefore your:

```
spring:
  integration:
    poller:
      cron: 0 0/30 * * * *
```

will be good.

NOTE: the `EnvironmentPostProcessor` has to be registered in the `spring.factories`.

Comment: The fix is here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/2366

Comment: Try workaround but it's not working. I guess it was executed before `PollerConfigEnvironmentPostProcessor`. I have also checked with adding order lowest but somehow EnvironmentPostProcessor doesn't consider it not sure.

Comment: Add `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor:\
org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.PollerConfigEnvironmentPostProcessor,\
com.idsk.des.rssrequestor.config.RemoveStreamPollerEnvironmentPostProcessor` in spring.factories and it's working fine